# Notation for strumming piano strings

Tags: piano, notation

At this piece of mine, I have the pianist (at an upright piano, with the front lid removed) at a certain point holding down a chord with his left hand and with his right hand strumming the strings of the piano.

I'm looking for a way to notate this on the sheet music. Is there any way to do it, or should I simply use words to explain what he is to do?

Comment: Ewwwww..... just don't.  yeah, I know,  I watched Elliot Schwarz (RIP) hit the strings with a plastic hammer, too;  Still, don't.  Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article may be helpful...

[Ishii (2005) The Development of Extended Piano Techniques in Twentieth-Century American Music](https://diginole.lib.fsu.edu/islandora/object/fsu:182093/datastream/PDF/view)

Example from the article...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Helmut Lachenmann's *[Guero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MChTWNDAg8)* for solo piano is replete with plucks and strums, albeit without strummed pitched chords.  So adapt his notation:  on the staff for the strumming hand, draw a thick diagonal line showing a strum's duration, direction, and force (see 2:30 in the video).  In a footnote, indicate that strums range only over undamped strings.